# Introduce math operator without requiring amsmath package

Tags: math-operators

Want to introduce a math operator named `sgn` but without using `amsmath`.

Comment: What's the problem with `amsmath`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without `amsmath` the "operators" are defined by the kernel like

```
\DeclareRobustCommand\log{\mathop{\operator@font log}\nolimits}
```

so you can similarly add to your preamble

```
\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand\sgn{\mathop{\operator@font sgn}\nolimits}
\makeatother
```

However, I second egreg's comment: what's the problem with `amsmath`?

Comment: I moved the extended licensing discussion to a [chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135753/discussion-on-answer-by-campa-introduce-math-operator-without-requiring-amsmath), so the conversation is preserved and can continue there, as it's a bit off-topic here.